# After user input, and I have autofilled 2 other textboxes, how do I stop my macro from running a search on the other boxes?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 textboxes, of which when you input data into any one of the textboxes, the other 2 will populate.

the codes are very long, so I've just added what it does at every line of code

```
Private Sub tbAC_AfterUpdate()

'Declarations

textbox 1 = tbAC
textbox 2 = tbAN
textbox 3 = tbIC

If tbAC is Nothing Then
    tbAC = ""

Elseif tbAC.TextLength > 0 Then

'Find tbAC in column AGC
Set MCodef = wsa.Columns(AGC).Find(what:=tbAC, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)

    If MCodef is Nothing Then
        Msgbox ("Invalid Code")

    Else
        Mcoder = Mcodef.Row
        tbAN = wsa.Range(AGN & Mcoder).Value
        tbIC = wsa.Range(AIC & Mcoder).Value
    End if
End If
End Sub

'It's pretty much the same if you fill in tbAN or tbIC

Private Sub tbAN_AfterUpdate()
End Sub

Private Sub tbIC_AfterUpdate()
End Sub
```

Given that user input in tbAN, I only want excel to run the sub tbAN_AfterUpdate and not the others. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have code that is triggered by entering data into the text box, but don't want that code to execute when using an alternate function in VBA, you can use:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

So if you are entering into TextBox1 and want to update TextBox2 when you enter into TextBox1, put this into TextBox1's Code.  You would use this when the code is first initialized, but you need to remember to reverse that at the end of the code or prior to the code terminating (e.g. through Exit Sub or some other forced command) as once EnableEvents = False, no code will trigger without setting it to:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: as I won't know which textbox the user would choose to input, where should I put them? my apologies as I don't quite know how it works

Comment: You would put this code in each of the textbox.AfterUpdate code at the start and the termination of the code.